# Solaris/Unix password change in-line

Tags: passwords, solaris, solaris-10

I'm trying to change the root password on Solaris in a single command. So far I've tried:

```
echo "password" | passwd --stdin root
```

returns illegal option -- stdin on Solaris.

```
echo -e "password\npassword" | passwd root
```

Returns a 'New Password' prompt.

Using Solaris 10 and Bash 3.2.51 for the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could do this via expect.
2. You could directly edit the /etc/shadow with sed or perl (of course you have to hash your password before, however as you want to hardcode it in your script you could use a different system, set the password manually copy it in your script and run the script of the target system. Or hash it on your own. is not that hard.
3. In solaris 11.3 starting with SRU4 there is a passwd -p to directly set the hash of the password. Would at least obfuscate the password by just putting the hash into the commandline.

But my real answer is: 
Don't do it ... just don't do it. By setting the root password this way you essentially write a note with pink,blue and green marker around it with the root password in public for everyone who is on the system able to run ps in the moment you set the password. And this don't include the problem of management software putting ps outputs into central repositories and so put this information totally out of control of the system administrator.

Comment: Expect is not available on Solaris 10. Perhaps I'll have to edit the /etc/shadow file, but this seems like a blunt solution..

Comment: Well there are packages with expect out there as third party packages. Furthermore there are libraries for example for perl mimicking the expect functionality.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as I went with option 2. Editing /etc/shadow. This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76313/change-password-of-a-user-in-etc-shadow) provided a solution.

Comment: @Jelphy *Perhaps I'll have to edit the /etc/shadow file, but this seems like a blunt solution..*  Not allowing `passwd` to read from `stdin` is a ***SECURE*** solution.  Allowing `passwd` to read a password from `stdin` creates a huge security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Passwd doesn't read from STDIN, and there isn't an option, on Solaris, to read from STDIN.

A possible solution is to use an `expect` script

see: http://www.unix.com/solaris/161023-solaris-passwd-script.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately expect is not available on Solaris 10. `which expect` shows no result.